# Avoid users to use Organization API by Redirect or Forward API

Tags: json, api

I have a Organization API which has more function than customers API (I am using platform  from a provider), customers want to have POST method /api/createOrder, however, this API is only available in Organization API. I don't know what I should look for, redirect API or forwarding API? Scenario: I want users to call POST API for example: middleAPI/api/createOrder (users will input data, ex: name of order, productID) and it sends data to POST organizationAPI/api/createOrder.
Can anyone give me an answer and step-by-step instructions (JS or Python is the best, I am not good at Java or .ASP)? (I am new). Thanks lots guys.

I have tried to look for redirect or forwarding API but don't know what is suitable.

Comment: Asking how to redirect a request, or call an API "under the hood" from one server to another, entirely depends on the technology you're using. Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit this question to make it appropriate for Stackoverflow, or it will be closed.

Comment: Hi Andy, because I don't have any idea about my scenario, which is suitable? Redirect a request or call an API?